# how to understand the behavour of the chart plot with date as x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

i have a dataset with two columns one containing values and the other one date .I want to plot a chart plot using geo_col() .When i plot those plots i get a chart for every existing month and year where the width of the chart is just exactely as the place dedicated to the point (month/year) in the x-axis.But when i change the column containing the date by adding some month/year which is chronolgically greater than those already existy then the widh of the chart becomes so large that it can lay over other points.please run the two chunks of codes below to understand what i want.The question is how to get charts similar to those of teh first code knowing that my datset is similar to the second.
code1:

```
dt <- data.frame(Mo = c("2011-07-31", "2012-06-30","2012-05-31"), Avg = c(6.98655104580674,7.66045407330464, 7.69761337479304))
df <- data.frame(Month = dt$Mo, AvgVisits = dt$Avg)

library(scales)
df$Month <- as.Date(df$Month)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = AvgVisits)) + 
  geom_col() +
labs(x = "1 Month", y = "Average Visits per User") +
  scale_x_date( date_breaks="months",date_labels = "%b %Y")+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

code2:

```
dt <- data.frame(Mo = c("2011-07-31", "2012-06-30","2013-05-31"), Avg = c(6.98655104580674,7.66045407330464, 7.69761337479304))
df <- data.frame(Month = dt$Mo, AvgVisits = dt$Avg)

library(scales)
df$Month <- as.Date(df$Month)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = AvgVisits)) + 
  geom_col() +
labs(x = "1 Month", y = "Average Visits per User") +
  scale_x_date( date_breaks="months",date_labels = "%b %Y")+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Comment: Specify the desired width (in days): `geom_col(width = 30)`

Comment: @Roland Bravo Roland!